# c++ function -- which date is first / last?

Tags: c++

One of my c++ function does some calculations based off of the values of other variables. The program asks for a bunch of information including start date and end date for 2 separate events.

`p1.start_date` and `p2.start_date`; `p1.end_date` and `p2.end_date` each of which have a day, month and year stored inside.

I need to set `combined.start_date` to which happens earlier (`p1.start_date` or `p2.start_date`) and I need to set `combined.end_date` to which happens later.

Could I please have some help in getting this started? Here is what I have now: http://pastebin.com/huJprtHj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, calculations based on dates can be done in two ways.

1. Convert the date into a "number of days since some fixed date (e.g. 1 Jan 1970)".
2. Use the date components (year, month, day).

If this is all you need to do, just comparing each part (with the "highest first") will work just fine - you just need a compare function that can tell you if date1 is less than date2.

The rest of your question should be really simple programming.

Edit: to clarify: For DATE calculations, days from a set date is fine. The system library functions have functions that use seconds [and in some systems, fractions of a second] for a complete time down to seconds. This is not required for comparing dates where a the time of day is not involved.

Comment: Isn't it usually *seconds* since a fixed date?

Comment: @JaminGrey dates really don't need to be measured in seconds.

Comment: @JaminGrey: At least in current systems, the most common increments are probably 1 second and 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: @DrewDormann I never said it *needed* to be, just that it's *usually* done in seconds in C and C++, because of the standard library: [time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/)

But I misread the original question - didn't see the format he was storing it in. =)

Comment: Right, I'm not talking about using the standard C time functions, but if you build your own date functions, using days is fine. Obviously, if you ALSO need hours, minutes and seconds, mixing it all into one function will also work. I have written a few "date/time" libraries a long time back, basically because what I needed didn't exist at the time. It was on 16-bit machines, so I used a 16-bit "days from 1 jan 1980" [this was ca 1984-85] and a 16-bit number for "minutes from midnight within the day". Seconds would have needed a 32-bit number, which was hard. For dates, days are good.

Comment: Hey guys, I don't need to calculate the time, just need to know which is greater. I suppose I can use a bool function like this: http://pastebin.com/huJprtHj. However, I'm not sure how to go about implementing that.

Comment: Your compare function looks about right. Please describe what is not working with it [and you may want to add it to the actual question].

Comment: @MatsPetersson Would I do combined.start_date = lessday(p1.start_date, p2.start_date)?

Comment: Well, you'll have to use `combined.start_date = p2.start_date; if (lessday(p1.start_date, p2.start_date)) combined.start_date = p1.start_date;` That gives the "earlier" start date of the two dates. The same but other way around to find the latest of two dates.

Answer (score 2):

At least assuming the dates involved are reasonably current<sup>1</sup>, stuff the month/day/year into a `struct tm` and use `mktime` to convert to a `timt_t`, then you can compare the two `time_t`s directly.

If you need/want to support a wider range of dates, you might consider [Ray Gardner's Julian Date routines](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/jdn.c).

---

1. At least in a typical case, dates from 1970 to at least 2038 will work.

Comment: I'm limited to using a `Date` struct with day/month/year.

Comment: @user2146412: You mean you're not allowed to use the standard library? Whose stupid idea was that?

Comment: I need to create a function, I posted my pastebin in below answer.

Comment: Since you just need a relative ordering, you could convert to a scalar  quite a bit more easily than usual by just treating it as if all years were exactly 372 days (12*31=372), and all months exactly 31 days, so `date = year * 372 + month * 31 + day;` This will leave some values unused, but relative order will be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Make this function.  I'm guessing that your dates are stored in an object named `Date`, since you don't specify.

```
bool operator< ( const Date& left, const Date &right )
{
   // ...
}
```

Then you can compare your date objects the same as if they were built-in types like `int`.

Comment: @Ben I can take the heat.  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann , this is similar to what I did in the mean time: http://pastebin.com/huJprtHj. Could you help me out getting this in my function?